# vscode not recognizing extensions

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-extensions

I am trying to use vscode (windows) to run a c++ based script. It involves running a launch.json file and cmakelists.txt file. However I keep getting the error saying you don't have an extension for debugging cmake. Should we find it in the marketplace? Even though I have installed cmake, cmake tools extensions and installed the latest cmake for windows. The same for json. I get the error you don't have extension for json with comments? I have installed git, gcc etc as suggested by online websites but still I keep getting this message. Any ideas what might be the reason or what I could be overlooking?

Comment: Installing git, cmake, etc. in your system enables you to use them. Have you installed the extensions for each one, through the vscode marketplace? Try hitting `ctrl+shift+x` in vscode and search for each extension.

Comment: Can you compile and run the script manually in order to verify you have all the necessary tools installed? Perhaps VSCode is just not seeing them.

Comment: Did you restart VSCode after installing extensions?

Comment: @AristotelisV , kiner_shah, Quimby Yes I have also installed the extensions in vscode and restarted vscode. 

I haven't tried that but I have the same extensions as the developer of the script and for some reason it doesn't work for me.